# Is there a library for parceling objects using reflection in Android?

Tags: android, reflection, parcelable, parcel

Is there a library that is capable of parceling objects in Android using reflection?
Something similar to Gson but for Parcelization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler. It seems to be a better solution.